# Pressing Alt + R in the UV Editing windows does not refresh the texture

Tags: texturing, uv, shortcut

As per title,

going into Image > Reload works, but the shortcut Alt + R does not work.
Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: have you checked in preferences in keymap it's called change the search type to Key-binding and search for Alt R. make sure reload texture is in there

Comment: @JBlock It is there as Reload Image. Also in the UV Editing window going ot Image > Reload it shows the Alt + R shortcut.